# Renaming a Telegraf measurement with a wildcard

Tags: influxdb, telegraf

I'm collecting measurements with a Telegraf client. Unfortunately, the measurement name isn't static. Rather, it encodes a timestamp (terrible design choice, but out of my hands) as part of its name.

For example, the following 3 lines represent 3 instances of the same measurement, but have different names:

```
info.quorum.2902864.agree: 6
info.quorum.2902865.agree: 6
info.quorum.2902866.agree: 5
...
```

is there a way to transform these measurement names into one static name? In other words, I'd like to transform these entries above to:

```
info.quorum.hello.agree: 6
info.quorum.hello.agree: 6
info.quorum.hello.agree: 5
```

I saw the rename processor (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/rename) - but that doesn't support wildcard.

I also saw the regex processor (https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/processors/regex) but that doesn't support measurement names.

any ideas on how to get this done?

EDIT: some background: the measurements are collected with http input, usin a GJSON path like a.b.*.c

EDIT2: here's what i'm trying to parse. the problem is with the key '2931747', which grows on each subsequent reading:

```
      "quorum" : {
     "2931747" : {
        "agree" : 8,
        "disagree" : 0,

     }
```

Comment: Is that a data point, or a measurement you suppose to send to? In terms of InfluxDB (check out the glossary: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/glossary/https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/concepts/glossary/)?

Comment: and the sample of your http input payload, plz

Comment: @YuriG thank you for taking an interest in my question. I've added the input payload.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So they put actual value there as the key... Downright, eh, unsmart, let's put it this way.

And I won't blame the writers of JSON format parser for not putting a handle for that situation.

So, the answer is: in current form, with HTTP plugin, available parsers & processors - there's no way to shape it in any proper form (unless you can drop that damned number-key completely - then it's trivial).

I would suggest you to push on data providers to make them stop this stupidity.

If that is not an option - you need to write your own processor for that, alas.

It could be either fully standalone (poll the http endpoint, parse the stuff, form a batch of line protocol records, send to influx) - or it could cut it off on producing lines in Influx line protocol as the its output, and be executed with **[Exec](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec)** input plugin

Comment: yes, I admit its not clever. I'll submit a bug report in their repo and work around it in a fork. thanks for your advice!